# Errors on generating controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gemfile

[Here is the error when controller is generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bO0E.jpg)

[Here is my Gem-file code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vawd6.jpg)

Help me to fix out this error

Comment: It's better to paste your code into a code formatted block. This allows viewers to copy and paste, and to see the issues immediately without clicking links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails errors always tell you the problem and where to look:

`unexpected local variable or method, expecting 'end' ....../Gemfile:28`

So on line 28 of the gemfile, there is something unexpected.

Look at line 28 and you'll see that you have

`gem 'selenium-webdriver' gem 'webdrivers'`

Which is not the same as any other line in the gemfile.  Each gem needs to be on its own line.